# MomentJS: how to parse dates in MM/DD/YYYY & DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

How can i use moment.js in both: Australia & USA time formats?

For example:

`07/08/2017` - is good for both time formats, but!

`30/08/2017` - is invalid for moment.js, but i can have such dateTime

You can check it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/2135/

Comment: Understand that while `07/08/2017` is *valid* in both formats, it represents two completely different dates (July 8th, and August 7th).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The parser is assuming that digits of the form XX-XX-XXXX are representing DD-MM-YYYY. If you'd like it to accept MM-DD-YYYY then you need to specify this.

eg `var now2 = moment('08/30/2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMM DD h:mm A');`

You can also specify an array of different formats that you'd like it to accept so that it will recognise both:

`var now2 = moment('08/30/2017', ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM-DD-YYYY']).format('MMM DD h:mm A');`

Comment: +1, but note that moment parser (using lastest version) simply fallbacks to `new Date(string)` that is browser dependent (so it is inconsistent). Moreover just fix the formats in your sample, because you used `-` instead of `/` and note that format order is relevant for ambigous inputs (like `07/08/2017` mentioned in the question).

Comment: "The parser ignores non-alphanumeric characters": https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Sure, but if you add the third parameter to enable strict parsing, you will have an invalid date, I see no benefit of using `['DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM-DD-YYYY']` instead of `['DD/MM/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY']`, that is way I pointed it out :).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that that the *first* pattern in the array that is valid will be the one that is used.  In the case of `07/08/2017`, this code would treat that as August 7th.

Answer (score 6):

Specify the format via a second parameter to the moment call

```
var now2 = moment('30/08/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('MMM DD h:mm A');
```

Otherwise there is no way for moment to know

Related docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wu6wwsvp/

Comment: how to call it for now? like moment() but with format?

Comment: i need something like: moment(now, 'DD/MM')

Comment: I feel like this is a different question but I think you're looking for:
`moment().format('DD/MM');`

A new moment defaults to the current date/time provided by the browser

Comment: `moment().format('DD/MM')` will output string... not an object

Comment: So you just want a moment of the current date/time? That is just `moment();`

Comment: @brabertaser19 - that's impossible.  Only strings have formats.

Answer (score 4):

In your fiddle you are using a very old version of moment (`2.2.1`), I suggest to upgrade it to lastest one (`2.18.1`).

Using a newer version, you will have a *Deprecation Warning* in your console:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Following the link (and [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs) you will discover that you have to specify format to parse you string correctly.

As Billy Reilly suggested you can use [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) parsing function. Please remeber that:

> Starting in version **2.3.0**, Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in valid dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

So the way `07/08/2017` will be interpreted depends on the order of the format in *array of formats* parameter.

Here a snippet with some examples:

```js
var now = moment('30/08/2017', ['MM/DD/YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY']);
var now2 = moment('08/30/2017', ['MM/DD/YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY']);
var now3 = moment('07/08/2017', ['MM/DD/YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY']);

console.log(now.format('MMM DD h:mm A')); // Aug 30 12:00 AM
console.log(now2.format('MMM DD h:mm A'));// Aug 30 12:00 AM
console.log(now3.format('MMM DD h:mm A'));// Jul 08 12:00 AM

var now4 = moment('30/08/2017', ['DD/MM/YYYY','MM/DD/YYYY']);
var now5 = moment('08/30/2017', ['DD/MM/YYYY','MM/DD/YYYY']);
var now6 = moment('07/08/2017', ['DD/MM/YYYY','MM/DD/YYYY']);

console.log(now4.format('MMM DD h:mm A')); // Aug 30 12:00 AM
console.log(now5.format('MMM DD h:mm A')); // Aug 30 12:00 AM
console.log(now6.format('MMM DD h:mm A')); // Aug 07 12:00 AM
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```