# Cannot convert spanish date to moment object without providing format

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, momentjs

I have an angular 5 project where I convert date to moment object as below:

```
moment(date).add(1, 'd').toDate()
```

For the spanish locale, date string is `'31/7/2018'`. In this case `moment(date)` gives me `Invalid da`. I looked into the moment instance and the locale is correctly set to `es`. I am using below code to load the locale data in moment

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es'

moment.locale(languageWithRegion);
```

In `.angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/locale",
]
```

The version of moment is `2.22.1`.

I have no idea what the issue is with the import.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MomentJS: how to parse dates in MM/DD/YYYY & DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975369/momentjs-how-to-parse-dates-in-mm-dd-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @JJJ This is not a duplicate one. The scenarios are completely different. I already have my locale set in moment object and hence should accept the format of that locale. I should not be required to provide the format.

Comment: If you think that you should not need to provide the format, you'll have to open a feature request with Moment maintainers. The locale only affects output, it doesn't change how it parses strings.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass format of passed value in momemt. It would be something like:

```
moment(date, format)
e.g. moment('31/7/2018', 'D-M-YYYY')
```

it would create a correct object of moment. After that you can do whatever you want on this moment object.

Comment: This solution is not possible for me as I support many locales and each time cannot have the format for each of them. If I have added the local data in moment object, ideally it should accept the format of that locale.

Comment: so in that case whenever you are changing language, you can set default input format in global variable and use that while creating moment object.